# Why am I getting this php warning? imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in

Tags: php, warnings

I'm trying to make a basic news system in PHP and I'm about to finish but I have a little problem in the image upload part. The problem is when I try to resize the image when it exceeds a certain size. The image uploads correctly but in a null state: the image is in black.
When I upload the image in the form of my html it displays me the following warning:

> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource,
>   string given in C:\USBWebserver
>   v8.6\root\CCCHermosillo\anadir_noticia.php on line 116

here is the part for the image upload:

```
   if($_POST['añadir']) {    
               if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {    
                 if($_FILES['image']['size'] < 500000) {    
                     copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "C:/USBWebserver v8.6/root/CCCHermosillo/image_upload/".$_FILES['image']['name']);    
                       $subio = true;    
                 }else{
                   // $ruta_imagen = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                    $ruta_imagen = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                    $miniatura_ancho_maximo = 200;
                    $miniatura_alto_maximo = 200;
                    $info_imagen = getimagesize($ruta_imagen);
                    $imagen_ancho = $info_imagen[0];
                    $imagen_alto = $info_imagen[1];
                    $imagen_tipo = $info_imagen['mime'];
                    $lienzo = imagecreatetruecolor( $miniatura_ancho_maximo, $miniatura_alto_maximo );
                    switch ( $imagen_tipo ){
                        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                            $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg( $ruta_imagen );
                            break;
                        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                            $imagen = imagecreatefrompng( $ruta_imagen );
                            break;
                        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                            $imagen = imagecreatefromgif( $ruta_imagen );
                            break;
                    }
                    imagecopyresampled($lienzo, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $miniatura_ancho_maximo, $miniatura_alto_maximo, $imagen_ancho, $imagen_alto);
                    imagejpeg( $lienzo, ("C:/USBWebserver v8.6/root/CCCHermosillo/image_upload/".$_FILES['image']['name']), 90 );
                    $subio=TRUE;
                 }    
               }
               if($subio) {    
                  echo "<br>El archivo subio con exito";    
               } else {    
                  echo "<br>El archivo no cumple con las reglas establecidas";    
               }    
               die();    
            }
```

the warning is given in this line:

```
imagecopyresampled($lienzo, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0,$miniatura_ancho_maximo,$miniatura_alto_maximo, $imagen_ancho, $imagen_alto);
```

Comment: because `$imagen` variable has `null` value.. check if it is going in the `switch..case` statement or not...

Comment: check what is in `$imagen_tipo` `IMAGETYPE_JPEG` is integer and `$imagen_tipo` is mime type (string) so you always get a null `$imagen`. check [image_type_to_mime_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php)

Comment: try using `case image_type_to_mime_type(IMAGETYPE_JPEG):`

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!! it worked!!